Deploying on Anchor
Devs and computer gurus, help me with this. I have been battling with this all day, and I don't seem to be getting anywhere. How do i resolve the error below? I am trying to deploy a token on anchor; it on testnet
PS C:\Users\jayde\maiden_token> anchor test
[2024-05-23T19:36:06.589006700Z ERROR cargo_build_sbf] Failed to obtain package metadata: cargo metadata exited with an error: error: failed to load manifest for workspace member \\?\C:\Users\jayde\maiden_token\programs\*
referenced by workspace at \\?\C:\Users\jayde\maiden_token\Cargo.toml
Caused by:
  failed to read `\\?\C:\Users\jayde\maiden_token\programs\*\Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. (os error 123)

I am tried to locate the rougue character, but I couldn't find anything out of the ordinary in the name, I have reloaded terminal etc. I have tried all I know of. Now, its time to seek external help.
Any tip would be appreciated.
